# Algorithm to calculate times in between low and high tide

Tags: javascript, algorithm, chart.js

I am trying to figure out the time and height between high and low tide.

This is what I have so far but I am not good with trigonometry and was wonder if someone knows the algorithm I need to write.

I have the height right but I need to get the time right.

I will also post the code for chart.js below.

[image]

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  var chartData = {!! json_encode($predictions) !!}

  var ctx = document.getElementById("tideChart").getContext("2d");

  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
      labels: [
          new Date("2020-10-18 04:20").toLocaleString(),
          new Date("2020-10-18 14:14").toLocaleString(),
          new Date("2020-10-19 04:53").toLocaleString(),
          new Date("2020-10-19 15:33").toLocaleString(),
          new Date("2020-10-20 05:37").toLocaleString(),
      ],
      datasets: [{
      label: 'Demo',
      data: [
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-18 04:20"),
              y: 10.035,
          },
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-18 14:14"),
              y: 8.517,
          },
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-19 04:53"),
              y: 10.240,
          },
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-19 15:33"),
              y: 8.394,
          },
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-20 05:37"),
              y: 10.353,
          },
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-20 16:57"),
              y: 8.342,
          }
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
      label: 'Best',
      data: [
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-18 18:39"),
              y: 9.3785,
          },
          {
              t: new Date("2020-10-19 04:53"),
              y: 10.240,
          },
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
          'rgba(100, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(94, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(123, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(25, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(113, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(215, 159, 64, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
      }
  ]
  },
  options: {
      scales: {
      xAxes: [{
          type: 'time'
      }]
      }
  }
  });
});
```

Comment: Confused why you need trig for this? Find the lowest point within one time range, find the next highest point, time is difference of the times, height is difference of the heights? If you have incomplete data it might get more complicated. Perhaps I'm missing something that makes this more complicated?